# F# seq<float> to ILNumerics in functional style

Tags: f#, ilnumerics

I have a F# query that returns `seq<float>`.

I was wondering how I could stuff the data within the `seq<float>` in a ILNumerics dense array (http://ilnumerics.net/FunctionRules.html) using an F# idiomatic functional style.

The data in the seq may correspond to a row, a column or the entire dense array.
References to F# code are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the C# example on [this](http://ilnumerics.net/quickstart.html) page, something like this should work

```
let toILNUM input = array(input |> Seq.toArray)
```